# Updating database with an AJAX call using a particular id

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, prepared-statement

I am attempting to do my first AJAX call and what I am trying to do is pretty simple, but my db is not being updated.

All I am trying to do is when I hit the accept button next to a user, for their id to be taken and sent with the new status 'Accepted' and for the status to change from 'Pending' to 'Accepted' for that particular user in my user_requests db table.

Nothing is being changed in the db and the only thing that is happening with the AJAX code is I get my #success message, but for maybe 0.3 of a second and it does not fade out.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong in my attempt?

```
<h2>Pending User Requests</h2>
<br />
<div id="success" style="color: red;"></div>
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    $run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($run);

    if( $numrows ) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            //comment added by php-dev : condition could be set in the query -->
            if($row['status'] == "Pending"){

                $pending_id = $row['id'];
                $pending_user_id   = $row['user_id'];
                $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $pending_lastname  = $row['lastname'];
                $pending_username  = $row['username'];

?>

            <!-- comment added by php-dev : useless form tag -->
            <form action="" method="POST" id="status">
                <!-- comment added by php-dev : useless input field, no field name -->
                <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $pending_id; ?>' id='pending_id' />
            <?php
                // comment added by php-dev : comparing string to boolean value true
                if ($pending_firstname == true) {
                    echo "Name - ". $pending_firstname . " " . $pending_lastname . "</br>" 
                         . "Username - ". $pending_username . "</br></br>"
            ?>
            <!-- comment added by php-dev : conditional form closing tag -->
            </form>
            <button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" 
                    value="<?= $pending_id; ?>"> 
                Approve
            </button>
            <button id="deny" type="submit" form="status" name="deny" value="Denied">
                Deny
            </button>
            <br><br><br>
        <?php
                 // comment added by php-dev : else statement misplaced -->
                ;} else {
                    echo "There are no Pending Requests at this time.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

My AJAX call...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.approve').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
            data: {
                id: $(this).val(), //the value of what you clicked on
                //you clicked on it so you know the status might as well hardcode it
                status: 'Approved' 
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
                // comment added by php-dev : for debug purposes, the #success should show 
                // the server reponse instead
                $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
                //do something with the data that got returned
                $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400); 
            },
            type: 'POST'
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

My userRequest_approve.php file to insert into db to update the status...

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$term = mysql_escape_string($term); // Attack Prevention
$pending_id = $_POST['id'];
$status = $_POST['approve'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO user_requests (status, date_responded) VALUES (?, NOW())"
    );
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User Request update prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $status);
    // comment added by php-dev : should be false === $stmt->bind_param ...

    if ( false===$stmt ) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User Request update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    // comment added by php-dev : should be false === $stmt->execute ... 
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
        die('User Status update execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }       
?>
```

Comment: I updated your answer by formatting it for more readability.
I also added some comments to your code, please check them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update, you should try this:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE user_requests SET status=?, date_responded=NOW() WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $status, $pending_id);
```

You also need a name attribute on your hidden so it'll be sent:

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $pending_id; ?>' id='pending_id'/>
```

**Original Answer**

I only see one issue:

This is the ajax request you're using:

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
       data: {
            id: $(this).val(), //<< id
            status: 'Approved' //<< status
        },
       success: function(data) {
            //do something with the data that got returned
            $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
            $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);//do something with the data that got returned
       },
       type: 'POST'
    });
```

Note that the data you're sending is `id` and `status`.

However, on the PHP side:

```
$pending_id = $_POST['id']; //yep
$status = $_POST['approve']; //does it exist?
```

You should be using

```
$status = $_POST['status'];
```

Comment: Ok, it is finally sending something to my db, but all of the info is blank other than my Auto increment id field, the status of Approved and the date. It is not using the current user's id to pull the info from them?

Comment: It is also inserting a new column row rather than updating the existing user.

Comment: But you aren't performing an UPDATE. Your are just inserting data in your database.

Comment: I just changed the query to UPDATE, but it didn't help. It just inserted another row. How can I update the current user's info?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change a column in another table (other than user_requests)?

Comment: No, just user_requests. If I click 'Approve' next to the name John, I want John's db row to be modified with this new status.

Comment: @Paul, try changing your query to my edit above. So, it will update the status/date_responded for your selected ID only.

Comment: @DaveChen just tried it and it doesn't update anything.

Comment: @DaveChen Still nothing. Is there anyway I can pull errors from my userRequest_approved.php file to see if that is causing this to not work?

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Do you have any idea why my message in this...`$('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
            $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);` ...doesn't delay or fadeout? IT basically shows up and goes away very quickly .3 seconds after it shows up..